# How to resize dimension of image before loading bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, bitmapfactory

Right now to load an image and then resize it (width/height), I do the following:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
options.inSampleSize = ImageResizer.calculateInSampleSize(options, x, y);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(x, y);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix,true);
return bmp;
```

The problem with this approach is that I first load the “bad” bitmap as `src` and then load the good bitmap as `bmp`.

Bitmaps are expensive. I would rather not load `src` but rather resize my bitmap before the first and only loading as `bmp`, perhaps while `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true`. In any case, does anyone know how I might do this well? **How do I resize the dimensions of an image efficiently?**

Comment: Is there a reason you need the bitmap to be *loaded* in a particular size, rather than being *rendered* in a particular size?

Comment: So as to not rework too much of the code, right now loaded is what I need, not rendered. It's a very long story.

Comment: The resizing is particularly important for me when the input image has the incorrect ratio or might need to be enlarged or one or two dimension

Comment: Then what you have is your only option, AFAIK.